# Is there a way to have line breaks in text without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: reactjs, line-breaks

I need to replace `\n` to `<br>`. But it is taking this as in text.

How can I do that without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: Why can't you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML for this - It is what it exists for? There isn't another way to do it because you only need one way to set raw innerHTML content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var yourNewValueWithBr = yourOldValue.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
```

After replacing this text, you will need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML to render it as HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I am using the same. But I need to Replace dangerouslySetInnerHTML with some other . Is there anything like that?

Comment: I don't believe there is. Maybe somebody else will comment on that.  I'm almost sure this is the only mechanism built into React.

Comment: Noooo! You need to convert `<`, `>` and `&` characters to HTML entities to make this safe. And this does not answer OP's question, who asked how to do this **without** resorting to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: I did update the title to make it more clear, but as you can see in the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31001066/revisions), it was in original version too.

Answer (score 24):

Insert the text as you normally would, and [fix the line breaks with CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

**Don't** use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` unless you *really* have to.

Comment: You are a life saver my friend

Answer (score 3):

This solution replaces `\n` to `<br>` and works without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
render: function() {
  var lines = this.props.text.split("\\n").map(function(line, n){
      return (n == 0) ? [line] : [<br />, line];
  });
  return <div>{lines}</div>;
}
```

But if you need HTML formatting, and **you're sure that your text is safe from XSS**, I would recommend to stick with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and a regex replace like Chris Hawkes said.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap'}}` for the wrapping div.

Now you will break line without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and `<BR>`

You can check browser compatibility over here:  [CSS SPEC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)