# How to render multi line text with return characters in React component?

Tags: reactjs

In my react app, I receive a text from the API like **"Fully furnished luxury apartment for sale in San Fransisco.↵↵The following features are available↵↵-Water↵ -T..."**.

I need to render this text as a **multiline text with blank lines** instead of these return characters. I used the following method to render the text.

```
<div className="previewSectionDesc">
  {<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: propertyDescription }} />}
</div>
```

But this is what I received **with no blank lines**.

**Fully furnished luxury apartment for sale in San Fransisco. The following features are available -Water -T...**

How can I solve this?

Comment: If the string is just text and line breaks, why not split up the string based on newline characters and then build a new element with `<br/>` tags instead, and avoid using the rather nasty `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` altogether?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001066/is-there-a-way-to-have-line-breaks-in-text-without-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos Yes, it has a relevant answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML will ignore the line breaks in your text when displaying it. If you want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you'll have to convert them to `<br/>` elements first:

```
<div className="previewSectionDesc">
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: propertyDescription.replace(/\n/g,'<br/>') }} />
</div>
```

You could also dispense with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` by splitting your text on linebreaks, then showing each line as a `<div>`:

```
<div className="previewSectionDesc">
  {propertyDescription.split('\n').map((line, idx) => <div key={idx}>line</div>)}
</div>
```

Still another way would using the `<pre>` element rather than a `<div>`, where HTML will preserve your linebreaks.

Comment: Thank you. All three methods worked for me. Can you please elaborate a little, why everyone advice to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as the last option? What is the drawback?

Comment: Using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can open you up to a [cross-site scripting (XSS) attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css white-space property to preserve the whitespace received.  `white-space: pre;`